# Is CSRF token validation required for http method other than POST and GET?

Tags: http, csrf

If I set actions for logged in users to be performed through HTTP methods other than `GET` or `POST`, then Javascript HTTP requests respecting the Same Origin Policy (SOP) or Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is the only way to perform those actions with credentials isn't it? (Since it seems to not be possible with basic HTML.)

Comment: Of course, reading server response isn’t required for performing the actions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exploiting CSRF PUT request](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106105/exploiting-csrf-put-request), [GET and POST request vulnerable to CSRF attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90023/get-and-post-request-vulnerable-to-csrf-attack), [How does the same-origin-policy protect against PUT/DELETE CSRF?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119560/how-does-the-same-origin-policy-protect-against-put-delete-csrf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern browsers, requests with methods other than `HEAD`, `GET` and `POST` can't be sent cross-origin without a CORS permission.

If your application verifies that the request method is, say, `PUT`, an attacker can't forge that request in a CSRF attack, unless you explicitly give permission, e.g. with an `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT` header.

See also: [Examples of access control scenarios](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Examples_of_access_control_scenarios)

Comment: [Even with Flash Player](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12650149/2284570) ?